# From within my controllers action, do I have access to HttpContextBase?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

From within my controllers action, do I have access to httpcontextbase?

I have a method that takes httpcontextbase as a parameter.

Comment: Ok it seems it works when I do this.HttpContext, just doing HttpContext refers to the non-base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have access to `HttpContext` which derives from `HttpContextBase`

so you can cast it like the following:

`(HttpContextBase) HttpContext`